# How to throw error from completable

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-databinding, android-room

I am a beginner for rxjava,room and mvvm architecture.I am trying to fetch a user from room database, using Rxjava.

when I get user successfully I want to show a toast and start another activity. and in case of failure, I will show an error message in text input layout.

I have try to do that using following code.

in my **Activity**, I have a method `authorizeUser()` which is called on button click.

```
private void authorizeUser() {

    loginViewModel.checkInDb()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.e("Action", "Complete");
                    showToast();
                    startAnotherActivity();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("Action", "error");
                    showError();
                }
            });
}
```

In my **ViewModel**

```
public Completable checkInDb() {

    Completable completable= Completable.fromAction(() ->
            userDataSource.getSingleRecordFromName(name.get(), password.get())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    isLoading.set(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(User user) {
                    preference.save(Constants.CURRENT_USER, user)
                            .subscribe();
                    isLoading.set(false);
                    isComplete=true;
                    Log.e("got","success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    isLoading.set(false);
                    passwordError.postValue(new Error("Username or password is incorrect"));
                    Log.e("got","failure");
                    isComplete=false;
                }
            }));

    return completable;

}
```

in **UserDataSource class**

```
public Single<User> getSingleRecordFromName(String strName) {
    return daoAccess.getSingleRecord(strName);
}
```

and in **DaoAccess class**

```
public Single<User> getSingleRecordFromName(String strName) {
    return daoAccess.getSingleRecord(strName);
}
```

Using above code, onComplete method is always called in activity, weather in view model, user fetched successfully or not

But what I want to do is, I want to throw an error or send a notification to the activity when there is error thrown (or on Error method is called in viewmodel). so that I can display error on my activity.

May be my question can be silly, but I am new to this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be better to maybe wrap the response in `LiveData` so you would get the subscription/lifecycle "for free", unless there is a **specific need** to have a completable on the UI, which I don't really any reason for it).

I would instead change your `Dao` to return `Observable` instead of `Single`, and then (one again this is not the optimal solution, should wrap into LiveData) you can return that `Observable` to the UI:

```
public Observable checkInDb() {

    return userDataSource.getSingleRecordFromName(name.get(), password.get())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    isLoading.set(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(User user) {
                    preference.save(Constants.CURRENT_USER, user)
                            .subscribe();
                    isLoading.set(false);
                    isComplete=true;
                    Log.e("got","success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    isLoading.set(false);
                    passwordError.postValue(new Error("Username or password is incorrect"));
                    Log.e("got","failure");
                    isComplete=false;
                }
            }));
}
```

And change your Daos

in **UserDataSource** class

```
public Observable<User> getSingleRecordFromName(String strName) {
    return daoAccess.getSingleRecord(strName);
}
```

and in **DaoAccess** class

```
public Observable<User> getSingleRecordFromName(String strName) {
    return daoAccess.getSingleRecord(strName);
}
```

So now your view can checkInDb() and handle these cases.

*PS: I'm assuming this `daoAccess` is not an API call rather a local DB (probably `Room`).*

Comment: which Observable I need to import? `io.reactivx` or `android.database` in DaoAccess class

Comment: yes you are assuming right I am using local DB (room) only.

Comment: and I don't want my view to access model (user) as I am using mvvm. so, I want to be handled all these case in view model and after that I want to notify the view (activity).

Comment: It would be the `android.database`. Regarding the leaking of the model to the view, that makes sense, so your `ViewModel` should use a mapper before sending anything to the UI :).